# How start and stop animation browser reload button javascript

Tags: javascript

I do not to reload the page. I need to start and stop the animation browsers reload button or icon or circle for all browsers and platform. Only javascript. Thanks.

```
add_js.onclick=function(){
// start animation browsers reload button or icon or circle
js.src='new_js.js';
};

js.onload=function(){
// stop animation browsers reload button
};
```

Comment: Browser reload / refresh button animation. new_js.js that example.

Comment: _"new_js.js that example"_ Can you create stacksnippets https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: http://imgur.com/4tzU4f7

Comment: Image does not reproduce what you are trying to achieve? What is "animation"?

Comment: :-) Press that button in your browser and you watch "animation".

Comment: By "animation" do you mean the browser reloading the current `location.href`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127497/discussion-between-alexander-ulyanov-and-guest271314).